# Is there a way in iOS to send a text message without presenting the message viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, imessage

Creating an emergency application that is supposed to be able to notify a pre planned contact or contacts with one click of a button.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

For instance an alcoholic would be able with one press of a button alert his sponsor he's having trouble. It should be automatic - not opening up imessages or mail and preparing the text and contact but just immediately doing so with a preplanned message/or email.

Comment: The way to do this is to make an API call to a backend that will then send the sms or email.

Comment: Can you give an example of this? Do you know of a way to use another app like Facebook to alert the user?

Comment: Building a backend to send sms or email is a complicated topic that can't be explained with a simple comment on here.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to send sms without showing view controller. It’s because of privacy. But you could make server, which sends sms. Make your app to send request to server for sending sms